# Customizing of code generation in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Im using IntelliJ IDEA 12. Can I customise code that is generated using "Refactor" functional?

For example I want to change the template of setting generation(Encapsulate fields) from:

```
public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
```

to

```
public MyClass setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do what you're suggesting in Intellij. [There are plugins](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6141?pr=idea), however, that can help with the generation of fluent interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can change the template for. The setters and getters is not one of them. You can vote for the feature request [IDEA-28206 Allow customization of generated getter/setter](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-28206).  *Engineer Dollery* is correct that there are some plugins for *inserting* customer setters & getters. But I do not believe there are any that will override the template used by the refactoring.