# Delegates code generation Intellij Idea

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, code-generation

I've met a situation, where I had to create five methods like:

```
public boolean addNames(String object) {
    return mNames.add(object);
}
```

And I tried to use code generation, but "Create delegates" return me just `add(Object o)` method, where can I change template to create delegates like getters and setters (I'm about smart prefixes).

When I tried to find a solution, I've found this question, it's nice too, but it's old, anybody knows solution to this too?
[Customizing of code generation in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695798/customizing-of-code-generation-in-intellij-idea)

Best wishes,
Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Delegate" action in IntelliJ IDEA performs a specific operation: it forwards methods to another object which has methods with the same signature and parameters. The code generation logic is not based on a template and cannot be customized.

(Generally, speaking, when the number of methods you need to create is five, it's much faster to create them by hand than to try to write a code generation template to create them for you.)

Comment: But this is interesting :) Thanks for the answer, I accept this

Comment: If it's interesting for you, you can write a plugin that would generate code for you according to any rules you like. :)