# Customize `Code` > `Generate` > `Constructor` in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, code-generation

I would like to customize the naming of the arguments generated by IntelliJ 2017.2 when choosing `Code` > `Generate` > `Constructor` to:

- Mark them `final`.
- Append `Arg` to the end of each variable name.
  For example, `firstNameArg` & `lastNameArg` rather than `firstName` & `lastName`.
- Annotate each argument with `@NotNull`.

Is there some way to customize the generation of constructor code?

This Question, [*Customizing of code generation in IntelliJ IDEA*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23695798/642706), is similar but (a) does not refer to Constructor, and (b) may be outdated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  The default parameter names are fine as they are.  Easy enough to change manually.  Personally I hate that kind of Hungarian notation for naming.  If you have so many arguments that manual renaming is a burden I'd say your constructor is badly designed.

Comment: I don't think it's possible now.  Btw. Why do you need that kind of feature?

Comment: The "Why" is to avoid ambiguity, avoid collisions, and for readability. Plus I edited to note that I would also like the to mark the arguments `final`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think IntelliJ provides this OOTB. You could, perhaps, use a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) via `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates`.

Template text:

```
private final $parameterType$ $parameterName$;

public $constructorClass$(final $parameterType$ $parameterName$$parameterNameSuffix$){
    this.$parameterName$ = $parameterName$$parameterNameSuffix$;
}
```

Change the "Applicability" of the Live Template to be:

- `Java > Declaration`
- `Java > Smart type completion`

Click on `Edit variables` and set the `Expression` associated with each of the variables as follows:

- parameterType: completeSmart()
- parameterName: suggestVariableName()
- constructorClass: className()
- parameterNameSuffix: camelCase(String)

Here are some screenshots showing it in action:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, this approach has some caveats (some of which *may* be deal breakers for your use case):

- It cannot be applied to a pre existing class i.e. it cannot interrogate a class, find its members and generate a constructor from those. Instead, it is a way of triggering declaration of class members and it creates a constructor on-the-fly as you declare the class members.
- If you want it to support multiple class members / constructor parameters then you'll probably have to create a live template for a single arg constructor and then copy that for a two-arg constructor and again for a three-arg constructor etc.